# Como colocar um gradiente na frente de duas imagens que são background?

Tags: css3, css-font-face

Eu tentei colocar o gradiente no cabeçalho que está sendo o "container" das imagens, mas ele só fica por trás das imagens.

Já tentei usar o `z-index` mas sem sucesso.

```
<body>        
    <div class="container">
        <section class="cabecalho">
            <header>
                IMAGEM DE CIMA TA AQUI
                <h1>
                    LOgo
                </h1>
                <nav title="Menu de Navegação">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span></span>Sua Conta</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>
                <div>
                    IMAGEM DE BAIXO 
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>       

</body>
```

---

Bom dia obrigado pela ajuda, 
mas e justamente isso que eu quero encobrir as duas imagens que estão como background, porém em vou controlar o gradiente de forma que fica possível visualizar a imagem. anexo 2 imagens com o exemplo que quero seguir, e o que estou fazendo.

[image: essa e imagem que estou seguindo quero usar esse efeito.]  [image: esse e o cabeçalho que eu fiz não to conseguindo colocar o gradiente pra ficar por cima dessas duas imagens, parece ser apenas uma mas e duas imagens.]

Comment: Seria bom vc incluir o que vc tiver de css na pergunta também. Ficou um pouco confuso, vc quer que a imagem fique por traz do gradiente da section tipo com um transparência para a imagem ficar aparecendo por baixo eh isso?

Comment: poderia adicionar o css ? ou  criar um jsfiddle.net e postar lá seu codigo para que vejamos

Comment: Cara fiz uma edição na minha resposta. Acredito que agora está mais de acordo com o que vc pretendia. Se possível coloque as informações que vc postou no campo de Resposta aqui na sua pergunta, utilizando o link "editar" logo ai embaixo da sua pergunta original. Se tiver alguma dúvida com a minha resposta é só comentar lá blz

Comment: Muito top eu consegue graças a essa sua mega ajuda, coloque as imagens como background e funfou direitinho. Muito Obrigado Sucesso. agora como faço pra  informar que essa resposta foi útil e fechar essa discussão ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

De acordo com as informações que o autor da pergunta acrescentou segue uma nova resposta, mais coerente com a dúvida.

Vc preica criar um pseudo-elemento no `.container` e colocar ele com `position:absolute` e o `z-index` maior que o dos outros elementos. Assim vc consegue botar esse elemento por cima dos outros, e não o `background` do `.container` *pai* por cima dos elementos *filho* que estão dentro.

```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #fff 100%);
  }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <section class="cabecalho">
            <header>
                    <img class="mix" src="http://unsplash.it/110/100" alt="">
                <h1>
                    LOgo
                </h1>
                <nav title="Menu de Navegação">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span></span>Sua Conta</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>
                <div>
                    <img class="opa" src="http://unsplash.it/102/102" alt="">
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

---

Sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa. Pois se vc colocar o gradiente por cima da imagem vc não vai conseguir ver a imagem, pois o gradiente vai ficar encobrindo tudo que está por traz.

Outra coisa, não é possível vc colocar o background do elemento "pai" que no caso é o seu `.container` na frente dos elementos "filhos" que estão dentro do desse elemento `.container`

Tem duas formas para vc tentar simular esse efeito caso queira "misturar" a imagem que está dentro do `.container` como o fundo gradiente que é o `background` dele.

Uma forma de simular isso é usando `mix-blend-mode` na imagem outra forma é com `opacity`. Nesse exemplo a seguir a imagem de cima esta com o `blend-mode` e a de baixo com `opacity` para vc ver o comportamento de cada opção.

OBS: Diferente do `opacity` que é possível apenas controlar a intensidade da opacidade variando de 0.1 até 1, o `mix-blend-mode` não tem o suporte tão bom dos browsers ainda, porém tem várias opções de mesclagem como vc pode consultar aqui https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mix-blend-mode-all

```css
.container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
.container .mix  {
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.container .opa {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <section class="cabecalho">
            <header>
                    <img class="mix" src="http://unsplash.it/110/100" alt="">
                <h1>
                    LOgo
                </h1>
                <nav title="Menu de Navegação">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span></span>Sua Conta</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>
                <div>
                    <img class="opa" src="http://unsplash.it/102/102" alt="">
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```